# Mysql service conflicts with current service

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I'm using inno setup to create a setup for my java application. The application uses mysql server 5.6.  How can i set user, password and host? Also, how can I load my database?

I use `net.exe` command to start mysql service, but the service conflicts with current service of mysql.  How can I get the service running in innosetup?

```
Filename: {sys}\net.exe; Parameters: start mysql; StatusMsg: Starting MySQL server;                Description: Starting MySQL Server; Flags: runhidden
```

Comment: I'm unsure about what your question is. If you want to run two different MySQL versions on the same machine you need to ensure they're using different ports and the services have different names.

Comment: I tried that alvaro but couldnot get the service running. Getting the error Can't create test file C:\Program Files(x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\T.lower-test.

Comment: Is that related to the original question or it's a new issue? Does the problem only happen within Inno Setup?

Comment: Again. And again. And again... I really must write that promised example for working with services in Inno Setup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must stop conflicting MySQL service process then you can create a database using this command line. Im sure InnoSetup provides access to shell executes.
mysql.exe --user=myid --password=mypwd --silent --force < CREATEDB.sql

**CREATEDB.sql**

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
USE mydb;

CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id bigint NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;

Insert Into table1 (name) Values('default row 1');
Insert Into table1 (name) Values('default row 2');

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * TO 'mydbadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mydbadminpwd';
```

Comment: Thank you whome..but the thing is couldnot start mysql serices at the same time..Getting the error as Can't create test file C:\Program Files(x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\T.lower-test

Comment: Is it possible to run shellexec commands from innosetup script? is net.exe same as dos console command starting services: NET <START|STOP> mysql

Comment: Using any way of command line for controlling Windows services from Inno Setup is wrong. It's like rolling a dice in a hope you roll 6. And blindfolded. Inno Setup won't tell you back if the service has started or not. You can't repeat your attempt or tell the user the real source of the problem if starting has failed. There's so many cons that it might be better to think about feature request for a new section like `[Services]` from which you would able to control services. It's a very frequent question and I bet that many people use a weak way with command line.